How to use alternative emoji fonts in Avalonia
Avalonia UI supports emojis which comes in full color.
How can I change the emoji font so that I can get variations of those emojis?
Emojis may have slightly different representations, I'm not sure if it depends on the font-family or the system OS, but I'm interested in being able to select the variant that fits the style of the app.
How can I get a variant of emojis that is just a single plain color?
Single color emojis are useful when using the emojis as button icons.
